# Android : Run app on physical device without installing?

Tags: android

I'm taking an Android development class and my desktop seems to hate Android emulation, so I've been running my builds on my Nexus 6. Is there any way to push the app to my device without installing it, so that I don't have to go in and delete the app every time I'm done testing it?

Comment: `Is there any way to push the app to my device without installing it` **NO**.

Comment: What's the problem with keeping an app on your phone?

Comment: @akodiakson

I just think it's messy to have it hanging out there afterwards.

Comment: Have you really thought this question through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to push the app to my device without installing it

No.

> so that I don't have to go in and delete the app every time I'm done testing it?

Then don't do that. That is rarely required.

Comment: Unfortunate, but I guess that answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

there is no way to run on device without installing it.

when you are trying to run app on your device, android studio sends install command as following:

```
adb install -r your_app_path_name
```

-r means the app will be reinstalled again on your device, so you don't have to unistall it every time you are going to test run.

Answer (score -1):

You are not required to delete app every time during testing. If you've to test your app say n number of times, simply Run your app and IDE will take care of updating your app during testing. Once you are satisfied with the final version and don't want to test further then you can delete it eventually.